# django model-How to apply user name filter on delete action

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with fields:

aseet_code

**d1:**

**d2:**

**user:**

etc.:

I want to put delete action filter on admin site ,so that logged in user can delete only if user field data and current logged in user is same.

**user==current_logged_in_user**

Otherwise it should raise exception like "This is not your data!".

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: how can I get current user when delete is called in django "model change form."

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the has_delete_permission method in ModelAdmin. It sounds like all you would need to do is override that:

```
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj = None):
    if request.user == obj.user:
        return True
    return False
```